# How-to make React Native lists bounce only from the bottom?

Tags: react-native, react-native-listview, react-native-flatlist, react-native-scrollview

I'm using a FlatList with a consequent ListHeaderComponent as the root component of my screen. I don't want the top of it to bounce on scroll, but I want to keep the bottom bouncing for UX'n'feel purpose as the FlatList supports infinite scroll. 
Any ideas how-to?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A solution would be to listen to `scroll` events and check whether [the `bounces` prop](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#bounces) inherited from `ScrollView` should be enabled or not. Note that I personally find this solution to be a bit of an overkill, but it works as expected.

You can find a fully working example at the following URL: https://snack.expo.io/SkL-L0knZ. You can preview it right in the browser and you can also try it on your mobile device with the [Expo app](https://expo.io/).

Here is the result (forget about the lag, as this was captured in the browser):

[image: react native scrollview bounces]

And here is the relevant source code:

```
export default class App extends Component {

    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { bounces: false };
        this.renderHeader = this.renderHeader.bind(this);
        this._onScroll = this._onScroll.bind(this);
    }

    _onScroll (event) {
        const scrollPosition = event && event.nativeEvent && event.nativeEvent.contentOffset && event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
        let newBouncesValue;

        if (scrollPosition < viewportHeight / 3) {
            newBouncesValue = false;
        } else {
            newBouncesValue = true;
        }

        if (newBouncesValue === this.state.bounces) {
            return;
        }

        this.setState({ bounces: newBouncesValue });
    }

    renderHeader () {
        const { bounces } = this.state;
        const style = [
            styles.header,
            { backgroundColor : bounces ? 'darkseagreen' : 'firebrick'}
        ];

        return (
            <Text style={style}>{ bounces ? 'CAN BOUNCE' : "WON'T BOUNCE"}</Text>
        );
    }

    renderItem ({item}) {
        return (
            <Text style={styles.row}>{item.key}</Text>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                { this.renderHeader() }
                <FlatList
                    data={DUMMY_DATA}
                    renderItem={this.renderItem}
                    onScroll={this._onScroll}
                    bounces={this.state.bounces}
                    scrollEventThrottle={16}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: wondering this would make an impact for performance as it updates state

Comment: It will if you set the state every time the onScroll dispatch. However, you can control updating the state only if the condition change.